# Running my Python script 24/7

Tags: python

Really newbie questions.
I made a Python bot which receives some data and has to analyze it,then prints everything. To use it, i need it to run for the whole day, the problem is that i can't leave my computer on 24/7, so i need a server or something similar for it and i need to be able to check what it prints whenever i want.

I made some research and found Heroku, but i'm having some problems understanding it: i tried to deploy it there and it's working but it prints all the stuff on a shell in the app's page and not on the webpage that heroku assigned to my app, so my problem is partially solved, since i can run it for the whole day but checking what it prints is way harder.

I was thinking of making it as a Telegram bot in order to have everything there but since it prints a lot of stuff, Telegram would not be the best platform for this kind of thing.

Is there another resource to deploy it and have it, for example, on a webpage?

Comment: Printing to a webpage requires some form of web-development (and server). If you got some root-like machine and you are only interested in reading the output, you can always use tools like [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) or [GNU screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) to log into your shell at some time and grab missed output.

Comment: How is your bot "receiving" data?

Comment: Just guessing a bit, but if you have a decent enough router, you can probably get a shell and run python on it (e.g. if it has access to entware/optware, or if you install openwrt). It could send the data to the syslog and you router web interface would show it in the logs.

Comment: As sascha said , you will need to make a webapplication for that,  but you can simply save the output into some kind of log file on the same server and reach it by YOUR_SERVER/log.txt or something like this.

Comment: how are you running your script? it might be an option to simply pipe stdout to a file... something like  `python yourscript.py >> gathered_data.txt`

Comment: @DwightGunning my bot is receiving data from a websocket.

Comment: I suspected it needed a web-development form to print on a webpage, i know something about Django and Flask but i'm really on a newbie-level, so what sascha and ChatterOne said looks way more interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into renting a cheapish cloud server (from digitalocean for example).
There are multiple ways of transferring data from your python script to your bot, either directly, through a websocket, or a webpage that displays it in a JSON format or otherwise.

Since you're already using python you could look into running a flask app on your node alongside your script or even combine them together.

If ran separately you could modify your script to output it's content into a file and then read the file with your flask application to display it on a webpage. For example:

```
with open('/tmp/data.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(yourdata)
```

then in your flask application:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def show_data():
    with open('/tmp/data.txt', 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
    return data
```

There are way more efficient ways of transferring data. Example above is a quick and dirty solution I wouldn't recommend running it due to security reasons especially if you are transmitting sensitive data.

Comment: I know something about Flask, guess i'll have to use it. It's not really sensitive data, basically it receives Cryptocurrencies trading data from a Websocket and the bot has to analyze them

Comment: @Gerard22 do you have the websocket URL? I feel like there is a more efficient way of feeding data to you bot than jumping through so many loops and hoops.

Comment: To connect to the Websocket and receive data from there i use a module which handles the connection, the site of the Websocket is Binance exchange